# How to restrict write/read access to HDD for certain apps

Tags: 14.04, mount, hard-drive, restricted-access

I have an old secondary internal HDD installed in my desktop PC on which I primarily do backups. I noticed that while the drive is mounted it seems that the whole system's performance seems to drop even though I have a pretty beefy PC(random hanging with IO indicator showing max). After I unmounted the HDD my PC's performance dramatically increased. I really want the backups to be automatic and at the moment thats impossible since the drive needs to stay unmounted the whole time unless I plan on using it. Is there any way I can leave the drive mounted, but only allow the backup application (default one that came with Ubuntu 14.04) to write an read from the disk? Or is there a setting I need to modify to prevent the old HDD from slowing the system down? Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you discourage it, my suggestion is to modify your backup-script to automatically mount your disc before running backup and unmount it afterwards.

There are other possibilities, which may or may not work in your case, depends on circumstances:

1. Are you running your backup as root?
2. Where are you mounting second HDD
3. Do you need to have access to this mount point for any other reason than running backup?
4. What kind ob backuping software do you run?

---

Suggested script:

```
#!/bin/bash
gvfs-mount -d /your/device/file
deja-dup
gvfs-mount -u "/media/cube/Backup HDD"
```

Comment: The backup script mod sounds promising, any idea how I might go around doing it? I can run the backups as root, the HDD is mounted at /media/cube/Backup HDD. I don't need to access this, I only use it for backups. I use the backup software that came with Ubuntu 14.04, I believe it is called Déjà Dup Backup Tool.

Comment: One more question (as I don't use Deja Dup), is it running with root privileges (do you enter password for sudo/graphical sudo)?

Comment: I don't need to run it with root as I'm just backing up some files in my home folder, but yes I can can it as root if need be.

Comment: Hi, I added script, which mounts the disk, runs deja-dup and unmounts it when you close deja-dup... It doesn't need root privileges...